# Update ClickOnce Application from local file

Tags: c#, clickonce

I've searched for this but I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

we have a file system that is downloaded automatically every day to each computer in the firm. I want to be able to include updates for several ClickOnce applications. The problem is that I need a UNC when setting up the updates in Visual Studio. Is there a way to access a local file using a UNC, with a path that has to include the local users name?

Is it possible to update programmatically and give the update request a path to look at?

Or if this is just not possible, is there another way to release me applications that will support updates from a local folder?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem by other way.
I created a server and hosted my app on **IIS Server**.
Aafter that i buy a domain for it if my server IP changed i just set the IP on my domain.
by the way if you want it in local you can use DNS to
UNC Patch is not a good way for use click once dynamicly